# How to configure Logback to filter out anything that does not have a specific marker

Tags: logback, marker

This must be a simple thing, but I am not getting it.

I have a marker, say "performance" that I use when logging. Also, I often use isDebugEnabled() etc. when log messages become expensive to build.

Now I want to configure logback that I can do these two things:

1) Log all statements in Logger foo.Bar that are debug or higher and use the marker "performance"

2) Log all statements across all Loggers that are debug or higher and use the marker "performance"

To achieve 1) I tried this:

```
<turboFilter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.MarkerFilter">
  <Marker>index-control-flow</Marker>
  <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
</turboFilter>

<logger name="foo.Bar" level="DEBUG"/>
```

Then also all log messages that are not tagged with this marker appear in the log.

To achieve 2) I tried omitting the logger line above and got only log messages with the marker, however, all log messages protected by a check of isDebugEnabled() are omitted.

Answer (score 1):

With help from the logback-users mailing list and some more RTFM I got it.

Changing my example to this here,

```
<turboFilter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.MarkerFilter">
  <Marker>index-control-flow</Marker>
  <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
</turboFilter>
```

together with isDebugEnabled(Marker) and setting the levels of the individual loggers gives me the solution to 1) (not exactly but good enough)

and the same with OnMatch ACCEPT gives me the setup for 2)

Answer (score 0):

Your best option to accomplish step one would be to add a custom Turbo filter that implements your criteria. I've adapted this from one of my Scala filters that does something pretty similar.

```
import org.slf4j.Marker;
import org.slf4j.MarkerFactory;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.TurboFilter;
import ch.qos.logback.core.spi.FilterReply;

public class ConditionalTurboFilter
  extends TurboFilter
{
  @Override
  public FilterReply 
  decide(Marker marker, 
         Logger logger, 
         Level level, 
         String format, 
         Object[] params, 
         Throwable t) 
  {
    if (marker != targetMarker) {
      return FilterReply.DENY;
    }
    if (!level.isGreaterOrEqual(targetLevel)) {
      return FilterReply.DENY;
    }
    if (targetLogger == null) {
      return FilterReply.NEUTRAL;
    }
    else if (targetLogger != logger.getName()) {
      return FilterReply.DENY;
    }
    return FilterReply.NEUTRAL;
  }

  void setMarker(String str)
  {
    if (str != null && str.trim().length() > 0) {
      targetMarker = MarkerFactory.getMarker(str);
    }
  }

  void setLevel(String str)
  {
    if (str != null && str.trim().length() > 0) {
      targetLevel = Level.toLevel(str, Level.ALL);
    }
  }

  void setLogger(String logger) 
  {
    targetLogger = logger;
  }

  @Override
  public void 
  start() 
  {
    if (targetMarker != null && targetLevel != null) {
      super.start();
    }
  }

  private Marker targetMarker;
  private Level targetLevel;
  private String targetLogger;
}
```

Then to use this, you would do:

```
<turboFilter class="com.yoursite.project.logback.ConditionalTurboFilter">
  <Marker>index-control-flow</Marker>
  <Level>DEBUG</Level>
  <Logger>foo.Bar</Logger>
</turboFilter>
```